# Can NovellAuthenticators (LDAP) be add to Weblogic using WLST Offline?

Tags: java, ldap, weblogic, wlst

I would like to create a WLST script to create my Weblogic domain. However I'm having problems adding the LDAP config.

```
cd("/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain")
cmo.createRealm("myrealm")

cd("/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain/Realms/myrealm")
cmo.createAuthenticationProvider("myLDAP", "weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NovellAuthenticator")
```

This is currently failing because at this point I don't seem to have a SecurityConfiguration object

```
No SecurityConfiguration object with name myDomain
```

Does this configuration have to be done online? Are there any other work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found, this configuration has to be done using WLST Online.

The script I have created looks something like this

```
connect("username", "password", "t3://ip:port");

edit()
startEdit()

create_AuthenticationProvider_54("/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain/Realms/myrealm", "value")
cd("/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain/Realms/myrealm")
cmo.createAuthenticationProvider("myLDAP", "weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NovellAuthenticator")

cd("/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/myLDAP")
set("GroupBaseDN", "value")
set("UserNameAttribute", "value")
set("StaticGroupObjectClass", "value")
set("UserBaseDN", "value")
set("UserObjectClass", "value")
set("AllGroupsFilter", "value")
set("Principal", "value")
set("UseRetrievedUserNameAsPrincipal", "value")
set("Host", "value")
set("StaticGroupDNsfromMemberDNFilter", "value")
set("StaticMemberDNAttribute", "value")
set("ControlFlag", "value")
set("UserFromNameFilter", "value")
set("Credential", "value")
set("GroupFromNameFilter", "value")

startEdit()
save()
activate(block="true")
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use online, but WLST offline will work with security providers that come with WebLogic, but not with custom providers. Of course, the NovelAuthenticator comes with WebLogic, so it should work.

Try

```
realm = cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm()
myProvider = realm.createAuthenticationProvider("weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NovellAuthenticator")
```